# How to detect the number of spatial streams

Tags: linux, wifi

I have AP (using hostapd) and connect to it using WPA Supplicant. How can I detect, see or calculate the number of spatial streams which used in data transmission? 80211n mode and another options enabled. Is there a tool which can indicate that spatial streams works?

Answer (score 0):

Using the mcs field of the radiotap header (if your nic supports it) will identify how many spatial streams are in use

Comment: Unfortunately, my wi-fi card can't catch it. Thanks for answer.

Comment: What tool does you suggest to do it, for example?

Comment: It all depends, put your wireless card in monitor mode and listen with wireshark, what header do you get, i,e. radiotap, prism, avs?